# How do I rotate a 3D vector using yaw, pitch, and roll?

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, rotation, trigonometry

I have no idea how I would go on about this, does anyone know how I can rotate x, y, and z using the yaw, pitch, and roll?, I can only manage to do 2D rotation, but that's not what I am looking for. This is the current code I have.

Yaw and pitch, and roll are supposed to be in degrees. Not radians.

```cpp
class Vector3
{//
public:
    float x, y, z;

    void rotate(float yaw, float pitch, float roll) {

    }
};
```

A solution that doesn't require a external library is appreciated.

edit :

```cpp
    void rotate(float yaw, float pitch, float roll) { //X Y Z Rotation
        float cosa = cos_r(yaw); float cosb = cos_r(pitch); float cosc = cos_r(roll);
        float sina = sin_r(yaw); float sinb = sin_r(pitch); float sinc = sin_r(roll);

        float Axx = cosa * cosb;
        float Axy = cosa * sinb * sinc - sina * cosc;
        float Axz = cosa * sinb * cosc + sina * sinc;

        float Ayx = sina * cosb;
        float Ayy = sina * sinb * sinc + cosa * cosc;
        float Ayz = sina * sinb * cosc - cosa * sinc;

        float Azx = -sinb;
        float Azy = cosb * sinc;
        float Azz = cosb * cosc;

        float px = x; float py = y; float pz = z;
        x = Axx * px + Axy * py + Axz * pz;
        y = Ayx * px + Ayy * py + Ayz * pz;
        z = Azx * px + Azy * py + Azz * pz;
    }
```

I tried this but it didn't work. cos_r and sin_r are functions that take degrees.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to roll your own linear algebra. Do us all a favor and use something like http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page .

Comment: @OldProgrammer I didn't really understand how it was explained there. And the case seems to be different.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are implementing your own 3D vector class, you *probably* want to implement some basic matrix operations too. In particular, you want [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions). The linked Wikipedia section shows the simple basecases for rotation around the X, Y, or Z axis.

Once you have that, you will find that "yaw, roll, pitch", i.e. [Euler angles or Tait-Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles) are just a way of applying rotations about the principal axes in a given order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rotation matrix to do the trick.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

All you need to do is to multiply the vector by the matrix of needed rotation.